# how to manipulate back date and exclude saturday and sunday?

Tags: php

How to manipulate the date and exclude saturday and sunday?. The objective is, I need to create a cron job that will run and execute on datas that were created 5 days ago,"BUT", saturday and sunday shouldn't be included in that 5 days period.

here's what I have so far

```
$numdays = 5;
$today = strtotime('now');
$start = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-'.$numdays.' day',$today));
echo $start;
```

if you try to run my code snippet above, it will show you the exact date 5 days ago `2016-02-10`. But that one doesn't "exclude" saturday and sunday in the computation. it should be be `2016-02-08`. So how to do that?

Comment: Do a loop of last 7 days and if weekend exclude it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PHP's date week of day, there are several versions, here is one using `N`:

```
<?php

$current  = new DateTime();
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');

$x = 5;
while ($x > 1) {
    // Check if day of week is not saturday/sunday (1 => Monday ... 7 -> Sunday)
    if ($current->format('N') >= 6) {
        $x++;
    }
    $current->sub($interval);
    $x--;
}

echo $current->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
```

Example [Run](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/384615c898582e4d2e090f470de41ef980fe2170).

Comment: I only need the exact date, not all the dates within the 5 days... like e.g the date I should get from my example should be 2016-02-08 and not 2016-02-10

Comment: If that's the case, don't you just need to go back a week?

Comment: @hasumedic: No. The last five days do not always include a Saturday or Sunday to skip over.

Comment: @sasori I have updated it so that it goes back exactly 5 days excluding saturday/sunday. I mis-understood your original request.

Comment: This breaks for [days that last longer than 86,400 seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second).

Comment: @PreferenceBean Good catch, I have updated so the `DateTime` object can do that work for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can get a whole week and discard the weekends, keeping the furthest element in the array as a result.

```
$days = array_filter(array_map(function ($daysBack) {
    $date = new \DateTimeImmutable("$daysBack days ago", new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    return (!in_array($date->format('N'), [6, 7])) ? $date : null;
}, Range(1, 7)));

$fiveWorkingDaysAgo = end($days);
```

Comment: No, because if you started on a Saturday, the answer should be Monday. If you started on a Sunday, the answer should still be Monday. Merely subtracting seven days is wrong.