# Generate random date excluding Sundays

Tags: php, datetime, random-data

A bit similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35399609/1469208), yet different.

I need to generate two random dates:

- First between `$startDate` and `$endDate`
- Second between generated first date and `$endDate`
- Both with random hour falling between `$startHour` and `$endHour`.

I am doing this like that:

```php
$createDate = new DateTime();
$updateDate = new DateTime();

$createDate
    ->setTimestamp(rand($startDate, $endDate))
    ->setTime(rand($startHour, $endHour), rand(0, 59), rand(0, 59));

$updateDate
    ->setTimestamp(rand($createDate->getTimestamp(), $endDate))
    ->setTime(rand($startHour, $endHour), rand(0, 59), rand(0, 59));
```

How to modify the above code to assure that both `createDate` and `updateDate` does not fall on Sunday?

<sub>As you can figure out from the above code, the `$startDate` and `$endDate` are integers and contains timestamps. The `$startHour` and `$endHour` are also integers, but contains pure hour numeral only.</sub>

Comment: Can you guarantee that there's a valid answer? (For example, there are suitable non-Sunday dates in the range, the hour range doesn't fall into daylight saving hour at the moment the required time is totally missing.) How important it's to have flat distribution for the randomness – for example, if initial random state would be Sunday, is it okay to add one day to use following Monday instead (which biases the randomness to select Mondays more often)? And the same questions for hours.

Comment: Probably it's only me, but you are totally overcomplicating a really simple problem. For me this is a task like: _Roll k6. If you get 5 then roll again_. Surely that you can run into endless loop. Probably your questions are valid (though I am very not math-savvy). But then again, this is a PHP-question asked in development (not math!) site.

Comment: It appears that you mean "between two dates" to be inclusive. You may wish to clarify that in your bulleted points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to modify the above code to assure that both createDate and updateDate does not fall on Sunday?

I modify your code to this:

```
$createDate = new DateTime();
$updateDate = new DateTime();

do {
   $createDate
       ->setTimestamp(rand($startDate, $endDate))
       ->setTime(rand($startHour, $endHour), rand(0, 59), rand(0, 59));
} while ($createDate->format('N') == 7); // Repeat until createDate is not a Sunday

do {
   $updateDate
       ->setTimestamp(rand($createDate->getTimestamp(), $endDate))
       ->setTime(rand($startHour, $endHour), rand(0, 59), rand(0, 59));
} while ($updateDate->format('N') == 7); // Repeat until updateDate is not a Sunday
```

Here, I used `do...while` loop to keep generating a random date until the generated date is not a **Sunday**. The `format('N')` is used to returns the day of the week as an integer, and `7` represents **Sunday**. The loop will continue until `format('N')` does not return `7`, ensuring that the generated date is not a **Sunday***.

*Note that this may be inefficient if the range of dates between `$startDate` and `$endDate` includes many **Sundays**, as it may take several iterations to find a date that is not a **Sunday**. In such, you may want to consider generating a list of all weekdays within the date range and then randomly selecting from that list, as answered by @waterloomatt [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57042750/21370707)

## Additional

> Generally "random" + "loop" = "infinite loop, or at least takes forever sometimes"

Add counter for a maximum number of attempts to prevent the loop from running indefinitely.

```
$createDate = new DateTime();
$updateDate = new DateTime();

$maxAttempts = 1000; // Maximum number of attempts to generate a non-Sunday date
$attempts = 0; // Counter for the number of attempts

do {
   $createDate
       ->setTimestamp(rand($startDate, $endDate))
       ->setTime(rand($startHour, $endHour), rand(0, 59), rand(0, 59));
   $attempts++;
} while ($createDate->format('N') == 7 && $attempts < $maxAttempts); // Repeat until createDate is not a Sunday

$attempts = 0; // Reset the counter for the next date

do {
   $updateDate
       ->setTimestamp(rand($createDate->getTimestamp(), $endDate))
       ->setTime(rand($startHour, $endHour), rand(0, 59), rand(0, 59));
   $attempts++;
} while ($updateDate->format('N') == 7 && $attempts < $maxAttempts); // Repeat until updateDate is not a Sunday
```

*The above may still has a possibility of infinite loop if the range of possible dates only includes Sundays and the maximum number of attempts is reached, so you could add additional logic to adjust the range of possible dates or handle the case where no non-Sunday dates are available.

Comment: Generally "random" + "loop" = "infinite loop, or at least takes forever sometimes". Consider the case that the start date is Tuesday, and the end date is the following Monday. Your first loop picks Saturday as `$createDate` and your second loop spins infinitely because Sunday is the only remaining day in the set. You can add guardrails and kludges to this approach to help _try_ to avoid long executions, but at that point you're playing whack-a-mole with edge cases as they crop up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As in my comment to @Sammitch answer, I have decided to pick / accept your answer for its simplicity, accepting in the same time the risk that I can run into either "very long running" or "never ending" generator loop.

Comment: Welcome, I'm glad I could help you.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble with the other answers is that having your loop bounded by a random condition can put you in the situation where the loop sometimes takes an extremely long time to complete, or puts itself into a state where it can *never* complete.

A constant-time solution would be something like the below where we simply generate a list of valid dates, and then pick randomly from *those* according to the rules set.

```php
<?php

function daysBetween(
    DateTimeInterface $start,
    DateTimeInterface $end,
    array $filters = [],
    DateInterval $interval = new DateInterval('P1D')
) {
    for( $cur = $start; $cur <= $end; $cur = (clone $cur)->add($interval) ) {
        foreach( $filters as $filter ) {
            if( ! $filter($cur) ) {
                continue 2;
            }
        }
        yield $cur;
    }
}

$tz      = new DateTimezone('UTC');
$start   = new DateTimeImmutable('2024-01-01', $tz);
$end     = new DateTimeImmutable('2024-01-31', $tz);
$filters = [ function($a){return $a->format('N') != 7;}];

$startHour = 9;
$endHour   = 17;

// generate a filtered list of days
$days = iterator_to_array(daysBetween($start, $end, $filters));
$dayCount = count($days);

// pick indexes for the dates in between
$createIndex = rand(1, $dayCount-3);
$updateIndex = rand($createIndex + 1, $dayCount - 2);

$create = $days[$createIndex]->setTime(rand($startHour, $endHour), rand(0, 59), rand(0, 59));;
$update = $days[$updateIndex]->setTime(rand($startHour, $endHour), rand(0, 59), rand(0, 59));;

$fmt = 'D Y-m-d H:i';

printf(<<<_E_
Start:  %s
Create: %s
Update: %s
End:    %s
_E_
,
    $start->format($fmt),
    $create->format($fmt),
    $update->format($fmt),
    $end->format($fmt)
);
```

Output:

```php
Start:  Mon 2024-01-01 00:00
Create: Sat 2024-01-27 14:29
Update: Tue 2024-01-30 13:32
End:    Wed 2024-01-31 00:00
```

Note that the upper/lower bounds for the create/update indexes are based on the assumption that neither can overlap with the start/end dates.

It should also be possible to approach the "no sundays" rule in a purely mathematical way based on the start/end and calculate the indices/offsets that way, but I'm just not feeling very math-y today.

Comment: While your answer is the best from professional standpoint, I have decided to accept the other one. Yours seems to me a little bit too complicated for the task. I understand that only an algorithm like yours (i.e. picking random date from a pre-generated, condition-sufficient range) is the only one that can truly prevent infinite loops. But in the same time I have forgotten (in my question) to mention that we are talking about very rare command-line script, used by system admins no often than couple of time per year. So, the possibility of running infinite with the other answer is acceptable.

Comment: BTW: I am really glad that you are _not_ feeling very math-y today! :] Having some years experience in PHP still required me to read your answer through 3-5 times to get the whole meaning of it. I have the feeling that if you'd start adding some mathematical model to avoid Sundays based on purely mathematical calculation then I could fail understanding your answer at all. Thanks again for everything.

Comment: Your concern about solutions that use loops that reject Sundays not terminating is well-taken. Suppose, for example, `$endDate` fell on a Monday and the generated first date fell on the preceding Saturday. One would have to account for that condition and if it were to occur it would be necessary to repeat the random generation of the first date...

Comment: ...I'm not sure about the computing times being long, however, as the limiting probability of neither of two randomly-generated dates being a Saturday is `(6/7)^2 ~ 0.73`. (By "limiting" I mean when the time between the first and last date approaches infinity.) Viewing that as a (Bernoulli) "success" the expected number of times through the two loops until a success is reached equals (only) `1/(6/7)^2 ~= 1.36`.

Comment: You could get rid of the array of non-Sunday dates between the start and end as follows. For the random generation of each of the two dates, let Ni be the number of valid dates that are between the beginning and end dates that fall on day-of-week i, for i = 2,..,6 (an easy calculation). By "valid" I mean, for example, that, when generating the second random date, if the end date were to fall on a Monday the preceding Saturday would not be included in N6 (assuming the OP means "between" to be exclusive when referring to pairs of dates).

Comment: ...Now compute the CDF: F[0]= 0, F[d] = F[d-1] + Nd/T, where T equals the sum of the Nd's. Let I be CDF's inverse function. If a pseudo-random number r between 0 and 1 is generated, then I[r] gives a random day of week d (other than Sunday). Randomly choose a number between 1 and Nd to obtain which day of week d gives the desired random date.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

function generateRandomDateExcludingSunday() {
    function getRandomDayOfWeek() {
        return rand(1, 7);
    }

    function isSunday($dayOfWeek) {
        return $dayOfWeek == 7;
    }

    do {
        $randomDayOfWeek = getRandomDayOfWeek();
    } while (isSunday($randomDayOfWeek));

    $currentDate = new DateTime();
    $currentDayOfWeek = $currentDate->format('N');
    $dayDifference = $randomDayOfWeek - $currentDayOfWeek;
    $randomDate = $currentDate->modify("+$dayDifference days");

    echo "Random date excluding Sunday: " . $randomDate->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
}

generateRandomDateExcludingSunday();

?>
```

Try add function, and no variables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I am getting your code correctly then you are _not_ taking one of a fundamental assumptions from my question. You have proposed a single function to generate _both_ dates (i.e. _create_ and _update_ date) and you are not taking into an account that second (_update_) date must be not earlier than first (_create_) date. Correct me, if I am wrong, but it seems that you have solved this problem only partially on contrary to other answers (or actually: you have solved it entirely, but you have introduced an intolerable deviation in results).